# How to check if two rectangles are "on" each other

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap

I want to check if the enemy_green_light (enemy_green_light_xenemy_green_light_y) and the player (x, y) touched each other. However, this code doesn't do what I want, and can say that they met even though they didn't.
The (x, y) is the left corner coordinates.
Thanks!

```
boolean before_x=(x<enemy_green_light_x)&&(x+player.getWidth()>enemy_green_light_x);
    boolean after_x=(x>enemy_green_light_x)&&(enemy_green_light_x+enemy_green_light.getWidth()>x);
    boolean before_y=(y<enemy_green_light_y)&&(y+player.getHeight()>enemy_green_light_y);
    boolean after_y=(y>enemy_green_light_y)&&(enemy_green_light_y+enemy_green_light.getHeight()>y);
    if(before_x||after_x)
        if(before_y||after_y)
        {
            pressed=true;
        }
```

EDIT: I tried this code too, and it didn't work.

```
float p_y_1,p_y_2,p_x_1,p_x_2,e_y_1,e_y_2,e_x_1,e_x_2;
    p_y_1=y;
    p_y_2=y+player.getHeight();
    p_x_1=x;
    p_x_2=x+player.getWidth();
    e_y_1=enemy_green_light_y;
    e_y_2=enemy_green_light_y+enemy_green_light.getHeight();
    e_x_1=enemy_green_light_x;
    e_x_2=enemy_green_light_x+enemy_green_light.getWidth();
    if(!(p_y_2<e_y_1||p_y_1>e_y_2||p_x_2<e_x_1||p_x_1>e_x_2))
        pressed=true;
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable to me. Try using shorter variables like gl_x instead of enemy_green_light_x. Abstract away gl_right_x into its own variable that you calculate on its own line. Abstract away gl_bottom_y that you calculate on its own line as well. Then use parenthesis, spaces, and new lines to make sure you make the sequence of evaluation more obvious and the code more readable. And if by then, you still don't understand your own code, make a drawing out of it and label your drawing with the variables you're using.

Comment: I tried it, and I still couldnt find what wrong. it getting pressed to become true sometimes, but not when it should. Im not sure when..

Comment: Your code is still very difficult to read and understand. You still need to break it down and make it clearer. Get rid of this long name enemy_green_light. May be, you could use your own native language to name your variables, but please use shorter names. In any case, the logic of (before_x||after_x) is reversed. It needs to be !(before_x||after_x) as in NOT (before_x||after_x). Also, you're only checking if a point is inside a rectangle, not if a rectangle is inside another one. Also, you may need a "=>" or a "=<" instead of ">" or a "<" depending on how you structure your logic.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://articles.leetcode.com/2011/05/determine-if-two-rectangles-overlap.html) you have an explanation how to determine If Two Rectangles Overlap

[image]

The solution is this expression

```
! ( P2.y < P3.y || P1.y > P4.y || P2.x < P3.x || P1.x > P4.x )
```

Comment: I tried it all and I looked up for this, but Im sure that my code is fine-and still, I dont understand why it dosent works.

Comment: Sometimes it recognizes it and others it dosent.

Comment: @ItaN, Your code is not fine. I still see two logic mistakes in it.

Comment: I added a try to this idea , and I just dosnt get it right from some resone.